# showing data in custom asp.net from sharepoint 2013(document libs/lists)

Tags: client-object-model, asp.net, object-model, odata

What would be best approach to show docs or list in an asp.net page from SharePoint 2013 on premises?
I would like to show documents and lists.
Which one is better CSOM,Odata?
With document libraries - Server side?

How would you handle authentications this sill be windows Auth.
Thanks in advance

Comment: is this asp.net application is hosted separately or you want a page asp.net page in SharePoint ?

Comment: Create a Provider Hosted App, Please check the link below http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Not sure why you are advising using Hosted Apps.All I want to is get some list/ libs shown in an asp.net page (Not in SharePoint but custom asp.net page different from sharepoint) Thanks

Comment: Please Use CSOM to pull the data from that List/Library as i guess that asp.net application is hosted somewhere else.